# Icenium Has No Server-Side IIS-Like Host, Correct?

Tags: icenium

If I have a working ASP.NET MVC 4 application with MVC in IIS on the back end and Angular and other scripts on the front end, and I'm looking to port that to Icenium to get it into app stores, is it correct to assume that any dynamic "server-side" stuff is outside of the scope of what Icenium will handle?  In other words, the server-side implementations of any AJAX calls, etc., will not be present in the application and I'll have to make the client-side code act as though it's communicating with an external third-party API (perhaps with new concerns with cross-domain AJAX that I didn't have to worry about before).

Answer (score 0):

Icenium is a Cloud Based IDE to create Cross Platform Mobile Apps. You can use any client side library like

1. jQuery Mobile
2. Kendo UI Mobile etc

to create apps. Now coming back to AJAX call scenario. Icenium has nothing to do with AJAX call. It is task of library being used to handle those and bring result back to apps.

For example if you are  using Kendo UI Mobile library then you can use KendoUI DataSource to create data source using AJAX call

Bottom line is Icenium has no role in making AJAX call etc. It is an IDE which allows you to create Cross Platform mobile Apps.

One more good news is that now Icenium plugin for Visual Studio is also available

Thanks 
/DJ